# Validity of ElGamal Signatures

Tags: number-theory, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

I'm trying this example question,

with $g≡5$ mod $p$ being a generator and $p$=$647$ being prime

The question says Alice publishes her public key $y ≡ 57$ mod $p$

And the question says Bob receives messages $245$ and $428$ with signatures $(556,123)$ and $(270,418)$ respectively, which of the signatures are valid.

I've tried calculating $(556^{-57}).(123)$ mod $p$   and $(270^{-57}).(418)$ mod $p$ to see if it computes 245 or 428 respectively but I'm not sure if thats the way to go.

Comment: There are a couple of different versions of EGDSA.  You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: I believe its ElGamal PKC

Comment: How is the algorithm specified in your text?

Answer (score 1):

The first signature is correct, if we follow the signature algorithm on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_signature_scheme) , where we have no hash algorithm but just use $H(m) = m$ because $m$ is already in $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

So we have $p = 647$, $g=5$, $y = 57$ (the public key of Alice).

If the message is $m$ and the signature is $(r,s)$ the verification check is:

$$g^m = y^r \cdot r^s \pmod{p}$$

and the signature is valid iff it holds.

For $m=245$ and signature $(r,s) = (556,123)$ we have $g^m \pmod{p} = 90$, while $y^r = 57^{556} \pmod{p} = 450$ and $r^s \pmod{p} = 259$ and $259 \times 450 = 116550 \pmod{p} = 90$ so the equation checks out.

Now you can check yourself that this computation for the second message ( $m=428$ and $(s,r) = (270, 418)$) fails.

Your own attempted computation makes no sense to me, but we *can* reconstruct all
computations that Alice made for the valid signature above, because all parameters are so small, we can find the secret keys etc.:

$x= 471$ (using a quick program, we only have < $p$ many options for the secret key ,so here we can try them out) and the chosen random mask $r = g^k \pmod {p}$ for some $k$, so in the case $(r,s) = (556,123)$ we have $k= 21$, as you can check. Then $k$ has an inverse modulo $p-1 =646$, namely $k^{-1} = 523$ (check that $523 \times 21 \pmod{646} = 1$), and $s$ is then computed as

$$s = (m-xr)k^{-1} \bmod{(p-1)} = (245 - 471\cdot 556)523 \bmod{646} = 123$$

giving the correct $(r,s)$ pair. Alice knows $x$ (her private key) and chose $k=21$ at random and then arrived at this signature. But the equation I gave is the way to check a given signature, because it only depends on the *public* parameter $y$ and the message $m$ itself and its signature $(r,s)$. The correctness proof(let) is on the linked Wikipedia page.